# find position of element in matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of lists. I want to find the position of the string "1" in one particular column col:

```
from numpy import transpose
col = 0
lists = [["0", "0", "N"], ["1", "0", "N"], ["N", "N", "N"]]
pos = transpose(lists)[col].index("1")
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Somehow importing transpose from numpy prevents me to use index(). How do we do this easily ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `np.transpose` converts your native `list` to `np.array` which is why you get the error.

Using numpy:

```
np.where(np.array(lists)[:,0]=="1")
```

Using native lists:

```
list(zip(*lists))[0].index("1")
```

`list(zip(*lists))` is a native way of transposing...

Comment: Nope. Still get error:

    import numpy as np
    col = 0
    lists = [["0", "0", "N"], ["1", "0", "N"], ["N", "N", "N"]]
    test = np.where(lists[:, 0] == "1")[0]
    print(test)

Gives:

    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: np.where(np.array(lists)[:, 0] == "1")[0]  Works great. Thank you